# Pandas. How do I find the 10 largest values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a csv table with a duration column. The data in it is like this: '90 min', '1 season', '3 seasons', '45 min', ...

I need to find the 10 largest numbers in it, as long as there is a 'min' in the row.
I was just able to find the maximum

```
print(df[df['duration'].str.contains('min')]['duration'].str.split('min').str[0].astype(int).max())
```

How do I find the 10 largest numbers? I don't know how to sort the numbers that are already split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), also for select column by condition is better use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
top10 = (df.loc[df['duration'].str.contains('min'), 'duration']
           .str.split('min')
           .str[0]
           .astype(int)
           .nlargest(10))
```

Or you can use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
top10 = (df.loc[df['duration'].str.contains('min'), 'duration']
           .str.replace('min', '')
           .astype(int)
           .nlargest(10))
```

Solution with sorting:

```
top10 = (df.loc[df['duration'].str.contains('min'), 'duration']
           .str.split('min')
           .str[0]
           .astype(int)
           .sort_values(ascending=False)
           .head(10))
```

EDIT: For see all columns is possible use [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) with convert minutes to another column:

```
df1 = df[df['duration'].str.contains('min')].copy()

df1['mins'] =  (df1['duration'].str.split('min')
                               .str[0]
                               .astype(int))

df1 = df1.nlargest(10, 'mins')
```

Or to same column:

```
df1 = df[df['duration'].str.contains('min')].copy()

df1['duration'] =  (df1['duration'].str.split('min')
                                   .str[0]
                                   .astype(int))

df1 = df1.nlargest(10, 'duration')
```

Comment: @loozmax jezrael actually built a machine-learning robot to automatically answer StackOverflow questions, which is why it took less than a minute. Just kidding :)

Comment: Can you tell me how I can output the rows from the other 'title' column, which corresponds to 10 'duration' values? I tried do it in the same solution, but it didn't work. Or do i need to redo it?

Comment: @loozmax - Do you need only one new column `title` or all columns ?

Comment: @jezrael All columns. 'title' and 'duration'. That is, there should be 10 lines.